# How come that sum of two lines in a triangle equals the third line?

Tags: vector-spaces

I have been looking into this question and cannot understand how they came to a conclusion in their solution.

we know that : $$(1) :\overrightarrow{a} + \overrightarrow{b} + \overrightarrow{c} = 0 $$ and that :  $$\left|\overrightarrow{a}\right|=1 ,\left|\overrightarrow{b}\right|=2,\left|\overrightarrow{c}\right|=3   $$

so as we see here, these vectors are lines of a triangle because of fact (1) but we know that sum of length of two lines in a triangle is bigger than the third line but a+b=c !

**they came to a conclusion that** : the vectors a,b,c are  collinear and more specifically, the angle between vector **a** and vector **b** is **zero** and the angle between the vector **c** and **a,b** is pi (180 degres).

**Can someone explain me how they came to this conclusion and how that fact(1) does not contradict the reality? **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : draw the base 3units and then try to draw other sides and try to make it a triangle and get to the conclusion for the angles.

Comment: okay I tried so it looks like a "collapsed" triangle ?

Comment: So what are the angles between vectors a and b

Comment: zero and between c and a pi I think I got it :D

Comment: Cool. Enjoy learning.

Comment: I am happy that it helped